# What is the difference between Dell XPS 15 1637sv2 (starting $999) and Dell XPS 15 1641sv2 (starting $1,349)?

Tags: laptop

What's the hardware difference between the Dell XPS 15 starting at $999 (1637sv2) loaded with a Core i5 and GTX 1050 for $1,149 total and the XPS 15 starting at $1,349 (1641sv2) with all the basic options?

So at Dell's xps-15-9560-laptop site I specced the following laptops:

http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/xps-15-9560-laptop/dncwxb1637sv2

- Core i5-7300HW processor (+$100 from base price)
- NVIDIA GTX 1050 with 4GB GDDR5 video card (+$50 from base price)
- 8GB DDR4-2400MHz ram
- 500GB 720RPM Hard Drive + 32GB Solid State Drive
- 56WHr battery
- $1,149.99 cost

http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/xps-15-9560-laptop/dncwxb1641sv2

- Core i5-7300HW processor
- NVIDIA GTX 1050 with 4GB GDDR5 video card
- 8GB DDR4-2400MHz ram
- 256GB PCIe Solid State Drive
- 97WHr battery
- $1,349.99 cost

Other than hard disk, battery, and cost, is anything different between the 1637sv2 and 1641sv2 as specced?  The $200 price difference seems a lot to pay just for a basic SSD and +73% battery capacity - although I guess for retail pricing that's probably par for the course.  Can I just buy the basic 1637sv2 model, swap in an SSD, upgrade the battery, and it'll be identical to the 1641sv2 model?

I noticed that the 1637sv2 doesn't have an option to upgrade the processor to a Core i7 while the 1641sv2 does.  Are the motherboards significantly different?  At least the CPU sockets must be different, right?

Any reason I should go with the more expensive 1641sv2 vs buying the 1637sv2 and swapping in the SSD and battery separately?

I'll be using the laptop for medical school, so want it to last at least 4 years.

Comment: 1. I highly doubt the batteries are compatible. Generally batteries are specific per model and can't be upgraded. 2) The difference with the SSDs is their connectivity. The second laptop uses a PCIe SSD, whereas the 500GB HDD is connected via SATA.

Comment: If the CPU is the same (both 7300HQ) then the socket must be identical. The chipset may differ, though I dobut it. What battery life will you require? what kind of useage will this laptop see? Heavy multitasking or just casual browsing with 1 or 2 tabs? What kind of weight will you be willing to lug around (IMHO, current gen shouldn't be much more than 1.2 kg)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I wanted to know primarily what the difference in chipsets / other motherboard differences is that's not advertised on Dell's site.  I think I may go with the more expensive option right now because the longer battery life would be nice for 4+ years of usage.